# Ambiguity between base and derived constructors

Tags: c++, c++11

I have designed the following code snippet that shows my problem (the original one is more complicated):

```
#include <string>

struct A
{
  A(int, int) {}

  A(int p1 = 0, std::string p2 = "", int p3 = 0) {} // string for breaking ambiguity with previous ctor

  // There are a lot more of constructors for A class 
};

struct B : public A
{
  using A::A; // I want to inherit many base constructors in order to save work

  // But I need this particular constructor and it should override the
  // equivalent base constructor
  B(int p1 = 0, std::string p2 = "", int p3 = 0) {}
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  B b(1); // gives "error: call to constructor of 'B' is ambiguous", what
      // of course is true, but I would want to inherit the other
      // base constructors. If I comment using A::A ==> this line compiles

  B b2(2, 3); // But if I comment using A::A ==> this line does not compile
}
```

So, my question: is there any way to break this ambiguity without hiding the lots of other constructors having the base class?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Ah, the great inheriting constructors mess](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4429.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The current inheriting constructors specification is...sort of messed up. Inheriting the `A(int p1 = 0, std::string p2 = "", int p3 = 0)` constructor implicitly declares three signatures: `B(int)`, `B(int, std::string)`, `B(int, std::string, int)`, only the last of which is suppressed because of `B`'s constructor declaration.

[N4429](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4429.html), a proposal to fix numerous problems with the current specification, passed design review at the last committee meeting, and, if adopted, would fix your problem.

A workaround is to write a set of delegating constructors in `B` rather than use default arguments:

```
  B() : B(0) {}
  B(int p1) : B(p1, "") {}
  B(int p1, std::string p2) : B(p1, std::move(p2), 0) {}
  B(int p1, std::string p2, int p3) {}
```

This suppresses all three signatures that would have been declared from inheriting that base class constructor.

Comment: Thanks @T.C. ... Uff! I have refactored my original derived class (its constructor had 5 parameters with default values, what implicated to write 6 constructors). A workaround but that works and rewards because the quantity of constructors in the base class is by far greater. I you discover another shorter way I would be grateful. A last question: when that proposed would be discussed and eventually approved?

Comment: @lrleon The next committee meeting is in October.

Answer (score 2):

If you define derived class constructor, you should call base class constructor in initialization list as follows:

```
struct B : public A
{
 // using A::A; // I want to inherit many base constructors in order to save work

  // But I need this particular constructor and it should override the
  // equivalent base constructor
  B(int p1 = 0, int p2 = 0, int p3 = 0):A(p1,p2,p3) {}
};
```

Please note, you don't need to use using statement to resolve ambiguity in your derived class  as `using A::A;`. When you derive publicly you will get all public and protected  components of base class will be available in derived class.

DEMO: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/52451127e54c8591

Comment: Yu'are right. Thanks. In the real application I did it thus and the problem is the same. In this simple test, I follow your advice (call A ctor) but the compiler still rejects it with the same ambiguity

Comment: @lrleon I added a demo for your reference

Comment: @Steephen: When you call the base constructor, you ought to pass it p1,p2,p3 as arguments not 0,0,0